# why does Create-Nuxt-App installs nuxt version 1.4.5?

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm a little confused because on the official nuxt site it says the current nuxt version is 2.5.X but when I create a nuxt app with `npx create-nuxt-app` and check the `package.json` under dependencies it says `nuxt: ^1.0.0`. When I check the nuxt node_module in its package.json it says `version: 1.4.5`.

So why does `npx create-nuxt-app` installs an old nuxt version and not the newest? The nuxt version doesn't impact the vue version, right? It says it uses vue `^2.5.17` which is pretty up to date.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you don't have a version of `create-nuxt-app` installed locally or globally. otherwise `npx` might take that one.

The current version of `create-nuxt-app` adds `nuxt: ^2.4.0` or similar, which matches all minor and patch versions that begin with 2, so the latest 2.x.y will be installed.

Comment: Thats wierd! I made sure I don't have `create-nuxt-app` installed locally but `npx create-nuxt-app` still uses `nuxt: "^1.0.0"`

Comment: For the sake of testing, did you try `yarn create nuxt-app`?

Comment: when using yarn it indeed uses `"nuxt": "^2.4.0"`

Comment: This is *usually* a sign of an old/cached `create-nuxt-app` version.

Comment: I checked if it is installed globally with `npm list -g` and couldn't find it and I tried `npm uninstall -g nuxt-create-app`, but the result is still the same. Do you have an idea what else I can try?

Comment: You can try `npm install -g create-nuxt-app`. I was having the same issue and did this and it worked. But it may mess up your npm permissions. Afterwards I got an `Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied` when trying to do npm install. I fixed it with `sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm` but it now seems I have to do `sudo npm install ...` for everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `npx create-nuxt-app@version`

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt 3 released with a new CLI tool (nicknamed Nuxi) to manage project, add components, etc.
Nuxi runs on Nuxt 3 but Nuxt <=2 remains on the `create-nuxt-app` tool

Nuxt 2 and 3 has their own CLI and 2 different commands to init a new project:

`npx create-nuxt-app` is for Nuxt <=2,

`npx nuxi init` is for Nuxt 3

[Documentation Here](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/commands/init#nuxi-init)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1-try to update your Node.js (V16 Recommended)

2-To create Nuxt2 projects you should use code below inside your Terminal

```
npx create-nuxt-app <PROJECT-NAME>
```

Comment: "V16 Recommended"—why? 18 LTS has been out for a while.