# How to check my create-nuxt-app version and upgrade it?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, create-nuxt-app

**Background:**

Previously, running yarn create nuxt-app myApp installs Nuxt v2.4.0 but today for example I noticed you downgraded to Nuxt v2.0.0. I did not change the development environment so I can not understand this behavior.

I did some search and complained elsewhere when I landed on this:

[image]

So the OP was asked to upgrade his [create-nuxt-app](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app) version.

**Question**:

But how to do that ? How to check which `create-nuxt-app` I do have ?

**Bonus:**

I read [why does Create-Nuxt-App installs nuxt version 1.4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691937/why-does-create-nuxt-app-installs-nuxt-version-1-4-5) and the answer says you: "Make sure you don't have a version of create-nuxt-app installed locally or globally." But how do you even install `create-nuxt-app` locally and globally ?

**Info:**

When I run `npm list -g | grep 'nuxt-app'` I do not get anything.

Comment: Try to invalidate your `npm` cache. Maybe this will help.

Comment: Also you don't need to install `create-nuxt-app` globally. It's just used with `npx`. Running `npx create-nuxt-app -v` I get `create-nuxt-app/2.9.2 darwin-x64 node-v10.16.2`. What result do you get after running that command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found an answer [here](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/issues/326) and [there](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/issues/325):

[image]

This execution [screenshot](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/issues/325) from @manniL on Github is helpful also:

[image]

Comment: I've updated [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57471295/11562913), would you please take a loot at it?

Answer (score 12):

You are fine. You don't need to do anything.

If you create a project with `create-nuxt-app` you get `"nuxt": "^2.0.0"` in your `package.json` which means that your project automatically uses the latest 2.x.x version of `nuxt`. Also if there'll be an update to `nuxt` your project with update itself.

And to answer your two questions:

- If you have `create-nuxt-app` installed in your project you can check its version using `npm list create-nuxt-app` (make sure you are in the project's directory). If it's installed globally you can check the version using `npm list create-nuxt-app -g`.
- You can install `create-nuxt-app` locally using `npm install create-nuxt-app` and globally with `npm install -g create-nuxt-app`.

Answer (score 6):

To check the existing NuxtJS Version of the project,
run `yarn why nuxt` on your terminal from the project root directory.

[image: yarn why teminal screenshot]

If you want to check for the VueJS version, install [Vue Developer tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) web extension, and check for Vue version.

[source](https://newbedev.com/how-to-check-a-projects-vue-js-version)

[image: Vue dev tool image with vue version]

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed create-nuxt-app globally using npm, first uninstall that. Using the below command.

```
npm uninstall -g create-nuxt-app
```

Then reinstall it. And the latest version of the package will be installed.

```
npm install -g create-nuxt-app
```